# What does the "+" mean in Mongodb for comparisons?

Tags: mongodb

so I'm trying to learn mongodb via nodeschool with local servers and I noticed in my exercises, that if I don't prefix the variable I am comparing with a '+' character, I don't get anything returned to me.

Here is the actual function in question, `arg` is first argument from the command line entered by the user:

```
parrots.find({
    age: {$gt: arg}
  },
  {name: 1, age: 1, _id: 0}).toArray(function(err, documents) {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    console.log(documents);
    db.close();
  });
```

however if I simply edit the line where I check if age is greater than the age provided by the user to

```
age: {$gt: +arg}
```

suddenly I get an JSON object returned to me that was within the database.

I'm just not sure why `age: {$gt: arg}` doesn't work since even in the documentation for the `find` method, there was no example that used `+`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments as they come from the command line are `String`s, the `+arg` syntax is a shorthand to cast that string to a JavaScript `Number`. It is not specific to Mongo, just a JS idiosyncrasy.